# sed заменить main.js на ./dist/main.js

Tags: bash, sed

нужно заменить main.js на ./dist/main.js с помощью sed
Написал команду: sed -i "s/main.js/./dist/\main.js\g" index.html
Но в итоге получаю ответ: sed: 1: "index.html": command i expects \ followed by text
Что не нравится программе? Подскажите правильное выражение.

Comment: используйте другой разделитель в `sed` `sed 's|main.js|./dist/main.js|g'`

Comment: Спасибо.Большущее